# How do you map an object within an array etc... with fromGson?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have some Json (this snippet is just the necessary stuff to see how far down I need to access):

```
{
  "media": {
    "audio": [
      "extraStuff": null
    ]
    "video": [
      {
        "extraStuff": null
      }
      {
        "ID": 1234
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to map the ID parameter to an object. I've tried a couple combinations of classes and stuff but I can't figure out how to access something that far down.

Example of what I've tried:

```
class Object {
    private Media media;

    private class Media {
        private Video[] video;
    }

    private class Video {
        private int ID;
    }
}

object = gson.fromGson(**Json from above**, Object.class);
```

Nothing seems to be working and with my setup (logcat on FireTV) I can't see the errors it is giving me other than "A problem occurred" generic stuff on the TV.

Edit: typo

Comment: I believe with `GSON`, every object you're mapping to it has to have fields with the same name. You are currently mapping two objects, one with `extraSttuff` and one with `ID`, so try adding `extraStuff` as an instance field to `Video`. 
Also, your JSON doesn't have commas between each element, so that may be causing errors in parsing, and you don't have `Audio[]` defined anywhere in your `Object` class. Lastly, I'm not sure if you can create a class called `Object`, since Java already has one implicitly defined by default, though I'm not entirely sure about this as a possible issue.

Comment: @Sal all of the syntax stuff you said at the end if just because I wrote this as an example. The code I'm working with doesn't have those errors and has many many more fields and things. I'll look at the new instance field.

Comment: The class name `Object` should not be a problem for Gson, it does not use the class names by default (though `Object` should in general be avoided in Java because it clashes with `java.lang.Object`). Not having fields for all JSON object members is not an issue either, Gson will just ignore them. Based on the code you provided, the issue is likely that the nested classes `Media` and `Video` are not `static` and therefore Gson cannot deserialize them.